# Python: KeyError: <__main__.State object at 0x7fd63d33be90> but key exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this line of code:
`g = g_score[current_state] + 1`
As you can see I dave a dictionary called `g_score` and `current_state` is an instance of `State` class.

Dictionary looks like this: the key is an Action class instance and value is an integer. so `g_score[current_state]` should give some number.

`State` declaration:

```
class State():
    def __init__(self, player=None, boxes=set()):
        self.player = player
        self.boxes = boxes

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.player, frozenset(self.boxes)))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.player, self.boxes) == (other.player, other.boxes)

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not(self == other)
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self
```

Also, it's in a loop and in each iteration `current_state` is taken from queue, but `g_score` for this, is added before putting it on the queue.
I get this error:

```
g = g_score[current_state] + 1
KeyError: <__main__.State object at 0x7fd63d33be90>
```

But debugger shows that `g_score` has such key and before I got this error `g_score[current_state]` has been called 3 times and no error occurred.

Comment: How's your `g_score` dict looks like?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, Can you show the what are the key, value pairs present in the dictionary?

Comment: If you're getting a key error, then the dict does NOT contain that key.  You must be misinterpreting the debugger results.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have updated the question

Comment: Can you show us the class definition for `State`?

Comment: @JohnGordon, sure, already updated. Sorry.

Comment: Did you add/remove items in `self.boxes` after the object was added to the dict?  Dict keys are supposed to be immutable (and thus always have the same hash), but your class allows for an instance's hash to change over time by adding/removing items from `self.boxes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just decided to use a list instead of State but as a dict key I use tuple.